# How to get number of hits by time regardless of Date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a sql view that should get the average number of hits by hour of the day, regardless of what day/date it is for traffic monitoring (12:00:00.000 - 12:59:59.999). Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Now I have the total, how do I get the average?  SELECT AVG("FUNCTION BELOW") DOES NOT WORK

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS total, DATEPART(hh, LogDate) AS HourOfDay
FROM         dbo.Log
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, LogDate)
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema with example data?

Comment: Why have you got this tagged both `MySQL` and `sql-server[-2008]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to DATEPART(hh,.....

Example  `SELECT DATEPART(hh,GETDATE())`

Since you are on SQL Server 2008, you can use the time data type, just convert to time

example

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE())
```

Then you can filter that also

Since I am not sure what your output is supposed to be like I am showing you both, but if all you need is to group by hour, then just do a  `datepart(hh....`.

Comment: Why bother converting it to a `Time` data type?

Comment: @Thomas - wouldn't that be a good idea considering I only need the time and not date?

Comment: @user54197 - By only extracting the hour portion of the value, you are already ignoring the date portion. No need to explicitly strip it to then ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

The query below may be good enough for you.  It divides the count by the difference between todays date and the minimum date in the LogDate column.

```
SELECT DATEPART(hh,LogDate) as Hour
,CAST(COUNT(*)as decimal)/DATEDIFF(d,(SELECT MIN(LogDate) from log)
,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as AverageHits
, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM log
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,LogDate)
ORDER by DATEPART(hh,LogDate) asc
```